# Why does this get stuck in a constant loop?

Tags: validation, loops, python-3.x, while-loop, uppercase

I can't understand why this wont work:

```py
EntryRow = input("Which row would you like to book for?")
Upper = EntryRow.upper()
while Upper != 'A' or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E':
    print("That is not a row")
    EntryRow = input("Which row would you like to book for?")
    Upper = EntryRow.upper()
```

Comment: Im no python programmer but your code doesn't have a way to escape the loop. If the user doesn't type a valid key you are just prompting and continueing in the loop. Perhaps you could put if entryrow is not equal to something in your while loop

Comment: @Ninja_Noob: The way to escape the loop is in the `while` statement.  If you don't know the language how can you offer good advice?

Comment: Ethan... you're right I was just looking at the code... you only need to understand logic to solve this. The code is saying if it does not equal a or b or c.... well if it equals a then it doesn't equal b. I think you need to replace your or's with ands.

Comment: Ethan if you're a programmer logic is logic regardless of language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'!=' has precedence over 'or'.  What your code really does is:

```
while (Upper != 'A') or 'B' or 'C' or 'D' or 'E':
```

Which is always true.

Try this instead:

```
while not Upper in ( 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' ):
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly write out each condition in full and combine them using `and`:

```
while Upper != 'A' and Upper != 'B' and ...
```

The interpreter takes `'B'` and `'C'` and so on to be independent conditionals which all evaluate to `True`, so your `if` statement is therefore always true.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `or` the wrong way.  (See [Andrew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27024194/208880) for the right way).

One possible shortcut is to use a containment check:

```
while Upper not in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'):
    ...
```